# Алгоритм для нахождение элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript

Скажем, у меня есть огромный массив (более 700к элементов)

```
[
  {q:"привет",a:"Привет. Как дела?"},
  {q:"пока",a:"Пока :c"},
  ...
]
```

И мне надо будет например найти `"привет"`, как это сделать не используя циклов?
Или предложите замену массиву на более человеческое.

Comment: цикл -- это одна из самых типовых конструкций практически любого языка программирования. глупо формулировать задачу "без циклов" -- даже если и можно будет так сделать это будет в итоге хуже, чем с циклами. Вам что нужно-то в итоге, шашечки или ехать? Решить задачу или обязательно не использовать циклы?

Comment: @AK используя циклы, происходит фриз. Ибо массив очень длинный

Comment: Могу посоветовать не пихать в массив 700к элементов в javascript. Есть еще такая [штука](https://habrahabr.ru/post/84654/) - можете попробовать. Заодно расскажете - как оно)

Comment: Там наверное цикл сложности n! )))

Comment: @Meupxan запили промис и будеш ждать без фриза )

Comment: @АлександрБелинский [Устарело](https://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/) и с ноября 2010 перестало поддерживаться. Рекомендуют использовать IndexedDB

Answer (score 2):

Так?

```js
var data = {
  "привет": "Привет. Как дела?",
  "пока": "Пока :c"
};
console.log(data["привет"]);
```

Comment: Да, это оптимальное решение. Хорошо бы в ответе написать сложность поиска с этим видом данных, что бы было понятно чем это лучше цикла.

Comment: Но ведь в вопросе массив объектов

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский >> Или предложите замену массиву на более человеческое.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ммм

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Там хеши и О(1)?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я думаю да (так должно быть по идее), и вот на хешмэме я ещё один ответ нашёл, так даже более красиво будет.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вот сейчас подумал что хорошо бы проверить...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Вот и я стал искать и ничего не нашел. Потому не рискнул вносить в ответ

Comment: Я бы это и использовал, но в данном случае никак не сделать схожесть, только на прямую обращаться.

Comment: @Meupxan Что значит `не сделать схожесть`?

Comment: Например будет надо найти `привет петух`

Comment: А в объекте есть только `привет`

Comment: @Meupxan А покажите кодом в своем вопросе, как Вы эту задачу решили для массива?

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей можно использовать тип данных Map. Поиск по нему идёт за константное время.

```js
let map = new Map([
  ['one',  'один'],
  ['two',   'два'],
  ['three', 'три']
]);

console.log(map.get("two"));
```

Документация по Map - https://learn.javascript.ru/set-map